# Intercambiar clases en elemento dentro de un modal de angular

Tags: javascript, angular, modal

Estoy estilizando un componente de angular y busco que al hacer click sobre el, este intercambie una clase de tipo "active" para asi aplicarle estilo, pero no funciona, cuando reviso en la consola, veo los hits al elemento pero nunca agrega la clase, si la agrego manual en la consola del navegador y hago click sobre el elemento me la retira, pero no la devuelve. Debe ser algo tonto pero no le encuentro pies ni cabeza.

Tengo ese input dentro de un modal

```
<label 
[class.active] = "isActive == true"
(click) = "isClicked()"
class="form-check-label " 
for="Monday">
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="Monday" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="checkmark">
   M
  </span>
  <span class="status">
    <span class="round-dot"></span>
  </span>
</label>
```

y tengo este dentro de su clase de componente

```
  public isActive = false;

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  isClicked() {
    this.isActive = this.isActive?false:true;
  }
```

Intente tambien con solo

```
  isClicked() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
```

y hasta con Vanilla JS pero nada

```html
<label 
onClick = "this.classList.toggle('active');"
class="form-check-label " 
for="Monday">
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="Monday" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="checkmark">
   M
  </span>
  <span class="status">
    <span class="round-dot"></span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si les pasa, luego de leer e intentar varias cosas parece que removiendo el label y cambiando por un div si funciona, solo que el label lo utilizo para marcar el input checkbox en el formulario, entonces tengo que cambiar el codigo para que Angular marque el input al hacer click sobre el div, quedo asi

```
<div 
[class.active] = "isActive == true"
(click) = "isClicked()"
class="form-check-label" 
for="Monday">
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="Monday" 
  value="Monday"
  [checked] = "isActive === true" />
  <span class="checkmark">
   M
  </span>
  <span class="status">
    <span class="round-dot"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Si alguien conoce que esto sea un bug o algo mal implementado les agradecere si lo comparten